# Cannot configure listener in Oracle NET Configuration Assistant

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

When I open Oracle NET Configuration Assistant, I cannot select Listener configuration as it is grayed out. I have tried "Run as Administrator" and nothing changed.

[image]

Can anybody help with this strange issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you are running NET Configuration Assistant from Oracle Client and not from Oracle Database.

To be sure, please check the Oracle Inventory XML file.

If you are under Windows, the file is normally located at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML\inventory.xml` or `c:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML\inventory.xml`.

If you are on linux, you can find the location of Inventory with this command: `cat /etc/oraInst.loc`. Inside it you will find `ContentsXML` directory with `inventory.xml` file.

Inside the `inventory.xm`l you can find all the installed "Oracle Home" directories. If you can find more than one line starting with `<HOME NAME=`, that means that you have more than one ORACLE HOME installed on your system (it can be Oracle HTTP Server, Weblogic, Oracle client etc...)

So now you need to find something that looks like an Oracle Home for Database server. It can look like this:

```
<HOME NAME="OraDB12Home1" LOC="/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1" TYPE="O" IDX="1"/>
```

Please notice the `OraDB` part. The client will have `OraClient` there.

Then go to the directory, that is inside the LOC tag. Inside it go into bin subdirectory and run the `netca` or `netca.exe` from here. You will have listener configuration available.